# Local storage key verification fails in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to generate html content based on the presence of a specific key in the local storage. The code is as follows:

```
    // Check if the user is signed in or not
    if(localStorage.getItem("token") === null) {
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = document.getElementById("welcomeview").innerHTML;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = document.getElementById("profileview").innerHTML;
    }
```

The profile view is always shown even though there is no token key set in the local storage:

```
localStorage
Storage { token: "undefined", length: 1 }
```

Why?

**Edit:**

The token is being set with the response value of an AJAX request:

```
function sign_in() {

        var uri, method, formId, $form, form_data;

        uri = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + "/sign_in";
        method = "POST";
        formId = "#signin_form_id";

        $form = $(formId);
        form_data = get_form_data($form);

        // Set-up ajax call
        var request = {
            url: uri,
            type: method,
            contentType: "application/json",
            accepts: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: form_data
        };
        // Make the request
        $.ajax(request).done(function(data) { // Handle the response
            // Attributes are retrieved as object.attribute_name
            // alert(obj.count);
            if(data.successSignIn === false) {
                // Login failed we show the welcome page
                alert(data.message);
                document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = document.getElementById("welcomeview").innerHTML;
            } else {
                // Login succeeded. We load the user's info, his messages and also a form in which he can type messages
                // Save the token received from the server. Could also be stored as a cookie
                localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                // Go to the home page
                go_home();
            }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                }
        );
        location.reload();

}
```

Comment: Token key is set and is a string `"undefined"`

Comment: just replace `if(localStorage.getItem("token")){...}`

Comment: @Sherali Turdiyev Thanks I was unsetting the key value and thought the key would be removed as well

Comment: you can also try if("token" in localStorage){...}

Comment: How are you adding/removing the key?

Comment: the correct way to remove the key localStorage.removeItem(key);

Comment: @epascarello localStorage.setItem('token', data.token); There is only one item I store.

Comment: Why did token return string `"undefined"` in your question? (instead of `undefined`)

Comment: @Sherali Turdiyev I ran localStorage.clear(); I'm not sure why there was still an entry there.

Comment: @Sebi. can you put or share your other codes (data.token, ...).

Comment: @Sherali Turdiyev Edited the question.

Comment: @Sebi. I edited my answer. If you have problem, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:** Try this for set item `localStorage.setItem("token", typeof undefined === data.token ? undefined : data.token)`. It is avoided to be string `"undefined"`.

I suggest that:

1) Replace to `if(localStorage.getItem("token")) {...}`

3) Also, you can do your example through ternary operator

```
var welcomeText = document.getElementById("welcomeview").innerHTML, 
profileText = document.getElementById("profileview").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = (localStorage.getItem("token")) ? welcomeText : profileText
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd never enter the `if` section as `"undefined" === null` is always false.

You'd want to check for `if(localStorage.getItem("token") === "undefined")` in your case.